# Lirc as a Raspberry IR blaster

Tags: wireless, lirc

I'm have a RP3 setup as a bridge to provide internet access to a TV, Directv receiver and the Audio system, also work as a Bluetooth audio receiver.

I will like to receive IR from the (multiple) remotes and blast/echo the IR into a closed cabinet where the equipment is hidden and, at the same time upon a Bluetooth connection, send IR commands to set the audio system into 'Aux' mode.

I have [LIRC](https://piface.github.io/pifacecad/lirc.html) working fine as IR receiver, also, I can teach keys from different remotes, however, I'm missing the 'repeater' portion, from the software and hardware perspective.

I think I can get a working IR diode from discarded remote but then what?

Answer (score 2):

I have used an IR LED from a discarded remote to create an IR blaster.

[image: IR blaster]

You just need suitable resistors and a transistor to interface it to a Pi.  I power mine from the Pi's 5V rail and switch it using a GPIO.

I used a NPN BC548 transistor.

The LED is driven from the 5V line. As I had no details on the IR LED I assumed it had a forward voltage of 1.7V and that it could handle 100 mA. If my calculations are correct I'm feeding it with about 70 mA.

You can find plenty of schematics on-line.

Anyhow, it works.

LIRC should handle everything else, i.e. sending the pulses with the correct carrier wave modulation.